# Move object to the position of another object in 2 different display groups

Tags: lua, coordinates, coronasdk, display

I have 2 display groups. Each group has few display objects inside it. Each display object has unique (x,y) positions. Each group itself has unique (x,y) positions. Both groups have `anchoreChildren = true`

What I would like to do is when I click on an object from the first group is to move to a corresponding object's position (while remaining a child of its original group) from the second group. I use a "transition" and the `object:localToContent` method to get the (x,y) of the target object.

What happens is the object moves "close" to the target but not at its exact position, there is always an offset.

Here is how I move it:

```
local x,y = target:localToContent( 0, 0 )
transition.to( object, {x=x, y=y, time=200} )
```

Basically what I need to do is:
I need to get the position of object2 inside group 2 relative to object 1 that is inside group 1 and move object 1 there.
simple  object2:localToConten`t doesn't work properly as I mentioned above.

Comment: I guess the simplest solution is to append the "offset" by getting the x and y from the target group.. or use positions relative to the sceneGroup..

Answer (score 0):

I understood what you want to do. You should calculate the distance of objects.

See this code:

```
local x1, y1 = object1:localToContent(0, 0)
local x2, y2 = object2:localToContent(0, 0)
transition.to(object2, {x = x1 - x2, y = y1 - y2, time = 200})
```

The code is working for me.